# Publish a number of collections with one publish function in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How can I create a number of collections on startup based on fields in my 'companydata' collection?

Currently I have on client and server:

```
datacollections = {};
CompanyData = new Meteor.Collection('companydata');
Meteor.startup(function(){
  DataCollectionList = CompanyData.find({},{fields: {'data':1}});
  DataCollectionList.forEach(function(doc){
    datacollections[doc.data] = new Meteor.Collection(doc.data);
    console.log(datacollections[doc.data].findOne())
  })
});
```

This does work server side as the server console prints the data objects on startup. However, client only prints undefined. How do I get this data on the client?

Comment: The CompanyData collection is visible on the client but none of the datacollections collections.

Comment: It is not available on the client because the `CompanyData` collection is not populated on startup. You will need to wait for the data to be ready before invoking it. Are you sure that you want to go down the collection-per-entity path?

Comment: As @MasterAM implies, dynamic collections are usually not a great pattern.

Comment: I would agree, however an external pyhton program loads data to the mongo database based on collection names created by users on the python side and these data collection be large. I was considerring a al data collection where AllDataColleciton =  [ "{randomname" : { "data": [ {all data objects }, ... ] }, ... ] is the structure but the nested arrays create performance issues on the large data imports, and I'm afraid the nested structure will complicate queries late on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
datacollections = {};
CompanyData = new Meteor.Collection('companydata');
Meteor.startup(function(){
  DataCollectionList = CompanyData.find({},{fields: {'data':1}});
  DataCollectionList.forEach(function(doc){

  datacollections[doc.data] = new Meteor.Collection(doc.data);
  //-----------------------------------------------------
  Meteor.publish(null ,function() { 
    // null name means send to all clients.
    return datacollections[doc.data];
  });
  //-----------------------------------------------------

    console.log(datacollections[doc.data].findOne())
  })
});
```